# How to secure uploaded files

Tags: file-uploads, security

I'm looking for the best way to secure files uploaded via a front-end form into a standard *File* field.

I need users to be able to upload a file, but I only want members of certain member groups to be able to access those files from the control panel. I also need the files to not be generally accessible from the front end.

1. Can I put an upload destination above web root.
2. If so, can those files still be accessed via the Control Panel?
3. Is there any way those files could be made available on the front end to members of authorized groups?

Also, is there another better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet: [Link Locker](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/linklocker) Does everything you want and more.

Comment: I should have clarified that I'm working with EE 3.x, and I don't think LinkLocker has been updated.